# Build error in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using eclipse HELIOS. I am getting the following error message whenever I build my project.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced such error? Is it a problem of eclipse or the project? It never occured to me before but for this project its happening. It says `NullPointerException` but that should not pop up such message.

Please help, its driving me nuts. I need to check in my codes but I cant test them due to this building error.

Let me know if more details is reqd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. It was a maven plugin issue. Cleaning up the repository solved it.

Comment: An extremely annoying issue with eclipse. In my case only re-installing worked.

Answer (score 0):

First try;

- Clean your all project from under project menu and eclipse tries rebuild.

Second try;

1. Remove your project from eclipse
2. Delete all files(eclipse project
   files like .project) except .java
   files and other necessary code files
   like .xml
3. And create a new project from
   existing these source codes.

Otherwise you can check your java compiler or eclipse builder path or builder version.

Answer (score 0):

Restart and Clean multiple times if it is taking to build more time. This should work if there is actual error present in source code.